# Join table groups on authentication in laravel 5.2

Tags: authentication, laravel-5, join

I am using laravel 5.2 to develop an application. Now what I need is I have two tables first one is users and second one is groups. Groups table is the parent table of the users table where groups_id is the column with foreign key with groups table (group_id). Now when login I am using the code as follows:

```
$users = User::leftJoin('groups', 'groups.group_id', '=', 'users.groups_id')->where('email', base64_decode(base64_decode(trim($request->input('user_login')))))->first();
```

where i used join to join the groups table. But It is executing perfectly but does not show the data in the session (Auth::user()).
So please suggest me how to add the second table in the session but only join the row with foreign key records.
Thanks.

Comment: you can add a relationship in user model with Group Model and than you can get user group at anytime by `auth()->user()->group()` where group is function name in user model in which you define relation

Comment: Please do me a favour. Please describe i have created a group model and what code block should i write on it.

Answer (score 0):

You have define a relation in User Model like this

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
  ......

  /*
   * Relation to Group Model 
   *
   */
  public function group()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Group','group_id','group_id');
  }

  ......
}
```

Now you can access authored user group at anytime , anywhere by  these line of code

```
auth()->user()->group()
```

**or**

```
$user = User::find($id);
$user->group();
```

and to retrieve users from a group you can define reverse of this relation in Group Model like this

```
   class Group extends Mdoels
   {
     ..........

     public function Users()
     {
          return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Users','group_id','group_id');
     }

     ..........
   }
```

you can find more information on docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships)